# What's the difference between Delphi and Rad Studio?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I can't find a feature comparison list. I believe they can both can create native unmanaged code, right? Does Delphi by itself feature RAD?

Comment: Delphi is the language and RAD Studio is the IDE

Comment: RAD Studio has two meanings. It is the IDE that hosts Emba's dev tools. In that meaning it is analagous to Visual Studio. But it is also the product name for an amalgam of different dev tools offered by Emba. @user, what are you looking for in your dev tool?

Comment: First there was Delphi. Then C++Builder. Then they decided instead of calling the IDE that was used to host both Delphi projects and C++ Builder projects "RAD Studio". That started at the Delphi 2005 product level, I believe.  If you bought Delphi you get "RAD Studio" but only the Delphi "personality" plug-in.  If you buy the full RAD Studio SKU you get the Delphi and C++ Builder plug-ins for the RAD Studio IDE. You also get other stuff that (confusingly, perhaps) does not plug into the RAD Studio IDE, but comes in the "bundle" (So Rad Studio is both a moniker for the IDE and a bundle SKU).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Both Delphi and RAD Studio contain the IDE and Delphi itself, so they both create the same unmanaged native code.

RAD Studio includes other product lines as well (XE2, for instance, included C++Builder, HTML5 Builder and Delphi Prism in addition to Delphi itself). The Delphi product simply included Delphi. Both products lines, though, use the same IDE for Delphi (and C++Builder, in the case of RAD Studio).

Comment: As of next week, RAD Studio no longer contains Prism.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. :-) That's why I said `XE2` and not `XE4`. XE3 included Prism, but not as part of the initial release, and no update to HTML5 Builder was released for XE3, so I didn't use it either.

Comment: You cannot buy XE2 anymore. And pretty soon you won't be able to buy XE3.

Comment: And expect XE5 in 6 months with an Android compiler that will produce 80MB Hello World Android apps.

Comment: Where did I say anything about **buying** XE2??? I listed the products that **made up** (note **past tense**) RAD Studio in that release.

Comment: A person that is talking about feature comparisons is presumably not interested in comparing out of date products that cannot be bought. All I am saying is that the .net component of RAD studio is now discontinued. I cannot understand the aggression in your comment.

Comment: David, I was listing the multiple products that made the difference between Delphi and RAD Studio. The version I chose to do that comparison is meaningless; I could have chosen the version that included C# Builder and Delphi for PHP. It still shows that RAD Studio contains multiple products while Delphi contains one. You first chose to nitpick about Prism, which again had nothing to do with what I said (it was a part of XE2). Then you chose to nitpick not being able to buy XE2, which had nothing to do with what I said either. The q asked about the difference between Delphi and RAD Studio.

Comment: No, I was adding extra information for the benefit of the asker. If the person asking thinks that they'll get a .net tool, then there will be disappointment.

Comment: So, if I develop a Delphi program, in Delphi, which is the IDE that I use??? Is it called Delphi IDE? Or RAD Studio? Or....

Comment: @Ultralisk The IDE itself is RAD Studio. You can get it in Delphi only (RAD Studio Delphi), C++ Builder only (RAD Studio C++ Builder), or full RAD Studio (both Delphi and C++ Builder) versions (RAD Studio). If you buy the full version, you can also start it in Delphi only mode (with the Delphi *personality*), Builder alone (with the C++ Builder *personality*) or with both loaded (RAD Studio *personality*) from the Start menu.

Comment: They really screwed-up the names of the languages/IDE: if I open my Delphi, the caption and the About box only says Delphi. There is no mention of RAD Studio. It is like they built the product first, then they decided to change its name.

Comment: @Antikythera: They *did* build the product (Delphi) first, back in 1995. At one point not too much later, they made it worse by naming both the product and the language *Delphi* (the lang was originally Object Pascal, which it's back to now I think). RAD Studio was created a few years later, and included Delphi, C++ Builder, and JBuilder (their Java product at the time).